# How do I replace a specific dataframe value while iterating?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df where the 4th column are dog breeds, I'm comparing it to a list of dog breeds (`breeds`). I'd like to replace the value in the data frame with 'NaN' if that dog breed is not in the list of dog breeds. The logic is working, but I cannot get the replacement right. How is this done? This is what I have been trying so far:

```
for index, row in df_2.iterrows():
    if not any(breed == row[3] for breed in breeds):
        df_2.replace([row[3], 'NaN'], inplace = True)
```

This example raised the exeption: `ValueError: ('Invalid dtype for pad_1d [category]', 'occurred at index tweet_image_number')`. Where `tweet_image_number` is actually column number 3, I'm not sure why it's looking there.

A sample of the df:

```
    tweet_id    jpg_url             tweet_image_number                              breed_probability_1 p1_conf breed_probability_2 p2_conf breed_probability_3 p3_conf
    0   43      666776908487630848  https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CUDeDoWUYAAD-EM.jpg     1   Seat Belt   0.375057    Miniature Pinscher  0.167175    Chihuahua   0.086951
    1   1939    860563773140209665  https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C_FWL0vVwAA13N7.jpg     1   Cardigan    0.583936    Pembroke            0.055979    Beagle      0.045896
    2   1471    779377524342161408  https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/77937...   1   Sundial     0.170921    Cash Machine        0.060359    Maze        0.054981
```

I'm sorry about the formatting, I don't know how to copy a dataframe into stack nicely

Comment: Please supply examples of your data. `df_2.head()` will be sufficient

Comment: do you have to iterate?

Comment: It's looking in column 3 because you tell it to look in column number 3 in each row with `row[3]`

Comment: `row[3]` is the fourth column

Answer (score 0):

I needed to escape the second loop, this solved it:

```py
for index, row in df_2.iterrows():
    if not any(breed == row[3] for breed in breeds):
        row[3] = 'NaN'
    df_2.loc[index, 'breed_probability_1'] = row[3]
```